# How to find the area of a strip from a cone

Tags: integration, geometry, area

Let's say we have a cone with radius height $h$ and radius $r$. Therefore the lateral side, let's call it $\ell$, would be $\sqrt{h^2 + r^2}$. If I want to find the area of the strip/region from $(\ell - 0.02)$ to $\ell$, how would  I go about doing that if I am not given the height of the cone? What is given is to me is $r$ is $0.2$.

[image: Visual representation of the section of the cone]

Comment: This problem does not have a unique solution; it depends on the height of the cone. Where did the problem come from, and what do you actually need from it?

Comment: $r$ is given, but is $L$ given? The strip has different area when $L = r$ (a flat circular ring) or when $L \to \infty$ (the curved surface of a cylinder).

Comment: Or maybe $r=0.2$ is the radius midway where the slant height is $L-0.01$ (not where the slant height is $L$)? Then there would be a unique solution. (See also: [Pappus's centroid theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem))

Answer (score 1):

If you know $l$ and $r$, then the circumference of the base of the cone is $2\pi r$ and when the cone is unwrapped to lay flat, the surface becomes a sector of a circle whose radius is $l$ and arc length is the aforementioned circumference.  Therefore, the angle of this sector $\theta$ satisfies the relationship $$\frac{\theta}{2\pi} = \frac{2\pi r}{2\pi l},$$ because the proportion of the angle $\theta$ of a full $2\pi$ rotation equals the proportion of the arc length of the full circle's circumference $2\pi l$.  Thus $$\theta = \frac{2\pi r}{l}.$$

The area of such a sector with angle $\theta$ and radius $\rho$ is simply $$A(\rho) = \frac{1}{2}\rho^2 \theta,$$ being the respective proportion of the area of the full circle; which for $\rho = l$, gives the lateral surface area of the cone, and for $\rho = l - \delta$ for some strip width $\delta$, gives the area to be excluded.  That is to say, the area of the strip is
$$A(l) - A(r - \delta) = \frac{\theta}{2}(l^2 - (l-\delta)^2) = \frac{\pi r}{l}\delta(2l-\delta).$$
In your case, $\delta = 0.02$ and $r = 0.2$, but since $l$ is not given, your answer will be a function of $l$.

Answer (score 0):

I am using symbol $s$ instead of $l$ to denote variable slant length.

You need to club the constants and variables separately for clarity.

$(s_{max}~,  \alpha=\tan ^{-1}(r/h), ~ r= s_{max} \sin \alpha,h= s_{max} \cos \alpha~) $ are known/given constants;

$~ (s, ~\text{ radius}  ~ y= s  ~\sin \alpha)$ are variables. Slant distance $s$ is measured from cone vertex upwards as shown.

[image]

Using integral calculus to find slant surface $A$ of cone:

$$ dA= 2 \pi y ds= 2 \pi \sin \alpha~ s\cdot ds$$

$$A= \pi~ \sin \alpha ~(s_{max}^2-s_{min}^2) = \pi \frac{r}{s_{max}}(s_{max}^2-s_{min}^2)$$

For $ s_{min}=0, \text {cone slant surface area}= \pi r s_{max} $

You know $ s_{max} = \sqrt{h^2 + r^2}, ~ s_{min} = s_{max}-0.02 ; $

Next, formula as above for the strip area.